# Position function return value not able to index a specific node in a collection

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below XSLT which works fine:

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:variable name="AddressNames" select="myUtil:getSecondXMLData()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <AddressName>
          <xsl:variable name="curValue" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$AddressNames//Item[$curValue]/names"/>
        </AddressName>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
```

My question is when instead of using a variable to contain current position and then use it to index a particular Item within collection of "//Item", I try only this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$AddressNames//Item[position()]/names"/>
```

I don't get the desired output...
Desired output:

```
<root>
    <AddressName>rahul sharma</AddressName>
    <AddressName>rahul sharma</AddressName>
    <AddressName>rahul sharma1</AddressName>
</root>
```

Wrong output recieved:

```
<root xmlns:myUtil="pda:MyUtils">
    <AddressName>rahul sharma</AddressName>
    <AddressName>rahul sharma</AddressName>
    <AddressName>rahul sharma</AddressName>
</root>
```

Input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<address>
  <item p2:type="ns1:sboeconnectCustomerAddressEntityItem" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <customer_address_id p2:type="xsd:string">19221</customer_address_id>
    <created_at p2:type="xsd:string">2015-01-21 13:11:13</created_at>
    <updated_at p2:type="xsd:string">2015-01-21 13:11:13</updated_at>
    <city p2:type="xsd:string">los angeles</city>
    <company p2:type="xsd:string">insync</company>
    <country_id p2:type="xsd:string">US</country_id>
    <firstname p2:type="xsd:string">rahul</firstname>
    <lastname p2:type="xsd:string">sharma</lastname>
    <postcode p2:type="xsd:string">90066</postcode>
    <region p2:type="xsd:string">Alabama@AL</region>
    <street p4:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" p2:type="ns1:ArrayOfString" xmlns:p4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <item p2:type="xsd:string">eeee</item>
    </street>
    <telephone p2:type="xsd:string">8065534367</telephone>
    <is_default_billing p2:type="xsd:boolean">true</is_default_billing>
    <is_default_shipping p2:type="xsd:boolean">true</is_default_shipping>
  </item>
  <item>
    <customer_address_id>19221</customer_address_id>
    <city>los angeles</city>
    <country_id>US</country_id>
    <region>Alabama@AL</region>
    <firstname>rahul</firstname>
    <lastname>sharma</lastname>
    <postcode>90066</postcode>
    <street>
      <item p4:type="xsd:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">eeee</item>
    </street>
    <telephone>8065534367</telephone>
    <is_default_billing>false</is_default_billing>
    <is_default_shipping>true</is_default_shipping>
  </item>
  <item p2:type="ns1:sboeconnectCustomerAddressEntityItem" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <customer_address_id p2:type="xsd:string">19222</customer_address_id>
    <created_at p2:type="xsd:string">2015-01-21 13:11:13</created_at>
    <updated_at p2:type="xsd:string">2015-01-21 13:11:13</updated_at>
    <city p2:type="xsd:string">los angeles</city>
    <company p2:type="xsd:string">insync</company>
    <country_id p2:type="xsd:string">US</country_id>
    <firstname p2:type="xsd:string">rahul</firstname>
    <lastname p2:type="xsd:string">sharma</lastname>
    <postcode p2:type="xsd:string">90066</postcode>
    <region p2:type="xsd:string">Alabama@AL</region>
    <street p4:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" p2:type="ns1:ArrayOfString" xmlns:p4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <item p2:type="xsd:string">CB-28</item>
    </street>
    <telephone p2:type="xsd:string">8065534367</telephone>
    <is_default_billing p2:type="xsd:boolean">false</is_default_billing>
    <is_default_shipping p2:type="xsd:boolean">false</is_default_shipping>
  </item>
</address>
```

The variable (AddressNames) contains the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddressNameCollection>
  <Item>
    <names>rahul sharma</names>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <names>rahul sharma</names>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <names>rahul sharma1</names>
  </Item>
</AddressNameCollection>
```

Comment: Can you also post the incorrect result you are currently obtaining?

Comment: Couldn't you minimize the code to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are asking. In XPath, a predicate filters the set of nodes selected by the location step. The predicate `[2]` in the expression:

```
/root/item[2]
```

filters the items. It is equivalent to:

```
/root/item[position() = 2]
```

where `position()` is evaluated as the position of an item in the node-set of items selected by `root/item`. The expression:

```
/root/item[position()]
```

is evaluated as:

```
/root/item[position() = position()]
```

This of course will return true for any item, so the predicate here is not doing anything.

What you're trying to do is something like:

```
/root/item[position() = current()/position()]
```

which <s>works in XSLT 2.0 (I think)</s>, but not in XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 1.0, you must store the position of the context item in a variable, and use that variable in the predicate (as you have done in your opening example).

Comment: No, `current()/position()` doesn't work. In general `$X/position()` returns the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4... N where N is the number of items in $X. Since `current()` is a sequence of length 1, `current()/position()` returns 1. You need to bind the value of `position()` to a variable, and then use the variable, as in the original post.